# Text in Text Widget as a variable

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

so I've got this little Text widget with a scroll bar and I've got a question. How do I make text in this Text widget a variable ? If I made this text a variable I would be able to open a text file and edit it's text or save the text I've written, etc or maybe it's a wrong way that I'm approaching this, is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no option to associate a variable with a text widget. You can achieve the same thing by using variable traces and widget bindings but it's rarely worth the effort.

The typical way to interact with the text widget is to read a file into a variable then use the `insert` method of the widget to put the text into the widget. Then, to save you just do the reverse -- get the text from the widget with the `get` method, and write the data to a file.

One tip: when you do a get, don't get the text from 1.0 to "end", use "end-1c" instead. If you specify "end" as the last character you'll get the implicit newline that tk always adds, meaning your text file will grow by one character each time you do a load/save cycle.