# Having multiple-page GUI in Python with several buttons

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, ttk

I am currently trying to implement a GUI for a task at work. I have found some open source code (see below) where we make a GUI having 3 pages where one can go between the pages using next/previous buttons. If you run the code you'll see what each button and so on is indended to do.

However, when you run the code and click the "count++" button, the overall count increases by one **and not the count for the individual page** (e.g. being on page 1 and clicking the count++ 4 times, still makes the count for page 2 or 3, 4 as well, and not zero). The same problem occurs when I try to update the text in each of the textboxes on each page (supposed to be number of clicks), as it won't update. I am not sure how to actually get to the textframe **for each individual page**.

Any suggestions on where to go from here? In the long run I would like to have scroll-down menus where the selections will be put onto each individual text-frame.

Thanks,

```
import ttk
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

class Wizard(object, ttk.Notebook):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kw):
        npages = kw.pop('npages', 3)
        kw['style'] = 'Wizard.TNotebook'
        ttk.Style(master).layout('Wizard.TNotebook.Tab', '')
        ttk.Notebook.__init__(self, master, **kw)

        self._children = {}

        self.click_count = 0
        self.txt_var = "Default"

        for page in range(npages):
            self.add_empty_page()

        self.current = 0
        self._wizard_buttons()

    def _wizard_buttons(self):
        """Place wizard buttons in the pages."""
        for indx, child in self._children.iteritems():
            btnframe = ttk.Frame(child)
            btnframe.pack(side='left', fill='x', padx=6, pady=4)

            txtframe = ttk.Frame(child)
            txtframe.pack(side='right', fill='x', padx=6, pady=4)

            nextbtn = ttk.Button(btnframe, text="Next", command=self.next_page)
            nextbtn.pack(side='top', padx=6)

            countbtn = ttk.Button(txtframe, text="Count++..", command=self.update_click) 
            countbtn.grid(column=0,row=0)

            txtBox = Text(txtframe,width = 50, height = 20, wrap = WORD)            
            txtBox.grid(column=1,row=0)
            txtBox.insert(0.0, self.txt_var)

            rstbtn = ttk.Button(btnframe, text="Reset count!", command=self.reset_count)
            rstbtn.pack(side='top', padx=6)

            if indx != 0:
                prevbtn = ttk.Button(btnframe, text="Previous",
                    command=self.prev_page)
                prevbtn.pack(side='right', anchor='e', padx=6)

                if indx == len(self._children) - 1:
                    nextbtn.configure(text="Finish", command=self.close)

    def next_page(self):
        self.current += 1

    def prev_page(self):
        self.current -= 1

    def close(self):
        self.master.destroy()

    def add_empty_page(self):
        child = ttk.Frame(self)
        self._children[len(self._children)] = child
        self.add(child)

    def add_page_body(self, body):
        body.pack(side='top', fill='both', padx=6, pady=12)

    def page_container(self, page_num):
        if page_num in self._children:
            return self._children[page_num]
        else:
            raise KeyError("Invalid page: %s" % page_num)

    def _get_current(self):
        return self._current

    def _set_current(self, curr):
        if curr not in self._children:
            raise KeyError("Invalid page: %s" % curr)

        self._current = curr
        self.select(self._children[self._current])

    current = property(_get_current, _set_current)

    def update_click(self):
        self.click_count += 1
        message = "You have clicked %s times now!" % str(self.click_count)
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("monkeybar", message)
        self.txt_var = "Number of clicks: %s" % str(self.click_count) #this will not change the text in the textbox!

    def reset_count(self):
        message = "Count is now 0."
        #ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0, message, "monkeybar", 1)
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("monkeybar", message)
        self.click_count = 0

def combine_funcs(*funcs):
    def combined_func(*args, **kwargs):
        for f in funcs:
            f(*args, **kwargs)
        return combined_func

def demo():
    root = Tk()

    nbrpages = 7    

    wizard = Wizard(npages=nbrpages)
    wizard.master.minsize(400, 350)
    wizard.master.title("test of GUI")
    pages = range(nbrpages)

    for p in pages:
        pages[p] = ttk.Label(wizard.page_container(p), text='Page %s'%str(p+1))
        wizard.add_page_body(pages[p])

    wizard.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    demo()
```

Comment: For a portable way to open dialog box, you can use [tkMessageBox](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-standard-dialogs.htm). First, `import tkMessageBox` , then open them with `tkMessageBox.showinfo(title, message)`. This would ease non-windows contributers wanting to run your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `update_click` method operate on the attribute `click_count` of your wizard. If you want different count, you could either create a class for your pages and thus, each object would manage its own count, or manage several counter, for instance in a list, the same way you handle your _children list.

For the former case, you can create a page class inheriting ttk.Frame with the body of your `_wizard_buttons` loop as constructor. In the later case, you could try something like this

```
class Wizard(object, ttk.Notebook):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kw):
        [...]
        #replace self.click_count = 0 with
        self.click_counters = [0 for i in range(npages)]

    def update_click(self):
        self.click_counters[self.current] += 1
        # and so on...
```

Regarding the Text widget update, you [can not handle it though a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4055447), it works with `Entry`(one line text field) but not on `Text` (multiline, rich text field). If you continue with `Text`, the usual recipe to what you seems to want is

```
text.delete(1.0, END)
text.insert(END, content)
```

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but I have trouble figuring out how to actually get to each page (or child), and thus create a class for each page... @FabienAndre

Comment: Thanks @FabienAndre! Really smart solution indeed, mimicing the that of the _children-list methodology.