# Want to print out message in a text area by using tkinter library

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to print out ftp system log messages into tkinter message box not in the CMD.

I tried to combine two sources as one. so the ftp related source and tkinter related sources come from each different sources.

```
import ftplib
from tkinter import BOTH, END, LEFT
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry("1000x600")

text_servermsg = tkinter.Text(window)

text_servermsg.place(x=20,y=150)

ftp = ftplib.FTP('FTP Server IP', 'ID', 'PW')
files = ftp.dir()

text_servermsg.insert(END, files)

window.mainloop()
```

There is a text box in GUI, and I want to print out ftp log messages in the text box not in the command line box.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text in Text Widget as a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055017/text-in-text-widget-as-a-variable)

Comment: In what way does the code you posted not do what you want it to do? What is the return value of `ftp.dir()`?

Comment: have you verified that `ftp.dir()` returns a non-empty string?

Comment: ftp.dir() comes from ftplib library. it shows sub-directory  when my program access FTP server.

Comment: I have fixed and make come true output as I wanted. the point was ftp.dir() as you pointed at. I have changed it to ftp.nlst(), and used insert method to text widget. after that, I could see the result as I wished. Thank you everybody for your help and guidance. everybody got me hint.

Answer (score 0):

```
import ftplib
from tkinter import BOTH, END, LEFT
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry("1000x600")

text_servermsg = tkinter.Text(window)

text_servermsg.place(x=20,y=150)

ftp = ftplib.FTP('FTP server IP', 'ID', 'PW')
files = ftp.nlst()

text_servermsg.insert(END,"\n")
text_servermsg.insert(END, "Hello there")
text_servermsg.insert(END,"\n")
text_servermsg.insert(END, "Now you have connected to FTP server")
text_servermsg.insert(END,"\n")
text_servermsg.insert(END,"\n")
text_servermsg.insert(END,"Directory list")
text_servermsg.insert(END,"\n")
text_servermsg.insert(END,"-----------------------------------------")
text_servermsg.insert(END,"\n")
text_servermsg.insert(END, files)

window.mainloop()
```